# Encrypt the elasticsearch data in k8s

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubectl

I have installed the elastic search image in k8s on a PV which is created using ceph-rook DFS.
When installing the ceph-rook the encryption mode was enabled

```
#pvc for elasitc search pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: core-pv-claim
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: rook-cephfs


#volume mount for elastic search pod

 volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /usr/local/elastic/data
      volumes:
      - name: persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: core-pv-claim
```

The pod got deployed successfully and the data is being saved in "/usr/local/elastic/data"
When i logged into the pod and changed the path i could see the date in rest in the "/usr/local/elastic/data" without any encryption

```
#kubectl exec -it elastic-pod12 bash 
#ls /usr/local/elastic/data
#your data
```

Is there a way to encrypt this data as well, or restrict the user from accessing the same using via kubectl

Comment: Does your user need to have permission to exec into pods?

Comment: No the user does not needs that permission , anyway to set that ?

Comment: Create a new role or cluster role for the user that only provides the actions they need on the resources they need

Comment: The users have access on the nodes? Or they are using kubectl with a specifc user to access? Maybe a Role could be the solution for you, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources)